# Kalman filtering; Computing cross-covariance between state vectors at two different time

Tags: covariance, estimation, kalman-filter

I'm interested in computing of cross-covariance between state vectors at two different times;
Cov{x<sub>k</sub>,x<sub>k-m</sub>}. For example considering x<sub>k</sub> & P<sub>k</sub>, the state vector and covariance matrix at time step of k, and x<sub>k-m</sub> & P<sub>k-m</sub> the state vector at time step of k-m, I want to express Cov{x<sub>k</sub>,x<sub>k-m</sub>} w.r.t P<sub>k</sub>. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question would be better on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) or [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) (where I found help with [a Kalman filter question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8860/more-on-kalman-filter-for-position-and-velocity)).

I don't have the time to do this calculation, but in principal I think it should be possible.  However, the answer will depend on more than just the x<sub>i</sub> and the P<sub>i</sub>, because there will be dependencies on all the other Kalman inputs (in particular the measurements and their covariances etc).   If I was going to do the calculation, I would start with the simplest m=1 case, and generalise from there.